# how to order freeradius attributes

Tags: attributes, freeradius

I am configuring Freeradius. Input message is Access-Request with Proxy-State = 3134
Freeradius succesfully performs authentication but he places Proxy-State at the bottom of Access-Accept. How can I canfigure that Freeradius places Framed-IP-Address at the bottom of the message?

It tried to configure "users" as:

```
381603854966   Auth-Type := Accept, User-Password == "123456"
       Service-Type = Framed-User,
       Framed-Protocol = PPP,
       Framed-IP-Netmask = 255.255.255.0,
       User-Name = 381603854966,
       Framed-IP-Address = 10.10.40.22,
```

but without success - freeradius still puts Proxy-State and the bottom of Access-Accept. I also tried to configure policy.txt file like:

```
if (User-Name == "381603854966") {
    reply .= {
                Framed-IP-Address    += "10.10.40.22"
    }
}
```

I also tried this in policy.txt:

```
    reply .= {
     Framed-IP-Address = 10.10.40.22
    }
```

didn't work. Anybody knows how can I place certain attribute at the bottom of the message?
Thank you, Mark

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The server will add Proxy-State to the request before forwarding it upstream, and it'll always add it at the end of the list of attributes.

RFC 2865 section 5 states:

> If multiple Attributes with the same Type are present, the order of
>      Attributes with the same Type MUST be preserved by any proxies.  The
>      order of Attributes of different Types is not required to be
>      preserved.  A RADIUS server or client MUST NOT have any dependencies
>      on the order of attributes of different types.  A RADIUS server or
>      client MUST NOT require attributes of the same type to be contiguous.

If your application requires ordering of attributes of different types, it's not implementing the RADIUS protocol correctly and should be fixed.